# Should I use file descriptors or streams for reading/writing to sockets

Tags: c, sockets, file-io

After a socket has been setup, is it better practice to use read(2) and write(2) calls on the socket descriptor, or to associate a stream with the socket descriptor using fdopen(3) and then use stdio(3) functions?

```
int sfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
// setup the socket using sfd
FILE * stream = fdopen(sfd, "r+");
// use fprintf, fscanf, etc
```

EDIT: I also unbuffer the stream

```
setbuf(stream, NULL)
```

To avoid having to flush it as mentioned in the comments.

I've been using this approach because it lets me reuse code written for FILE* streams, and I have the advantage of being able to use format strings (I am working with human readable text). GNU seems to be suggesting that this is a good idea.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-File-Descriptors.html

However usually when I see code using sockets, the socket descriptor is used instead of a stream for all operations. Is there an advantage to using the lower level functions?

Comment: Remember that C file streams are by default buffered, so you have to remember to flush them yourself when sending. And reading may block even if you made the socket non-blocking.

Comment: If your performance with the wrapped I/O is good enough, and it leaves the code simple, just keep using it.

Comment: In my opinnion, read() and write() make handling of error conditions more straight forward, since they dont try to mask any of them.

Comment: Using C file streams with sockets is a good recipe for trouble, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need more precise control and handling of error conditions, use `read` and `write`. If you don't, and prefer the convenience of stdio functions, then use the `FILE*` wrapper.

One problem with using a `FILE *` wrapper is that you don't have control over how and when data is actually written to the socket. This can result in inefficient network utilization and excessive delays (due to Nagle's algorithm interacting with delayed ACK) if you're not careful.

I would recommend using `read` and `write` directly if this is a high-performance Internet application.

Comment: Well, even more precise control can be achived with `recv` and `send` because they allow to specify flags, like `MSG_NOSIGNAL`.