# can I call recv() for returning most one line?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, serial-port

When communicating with serial port, I can set the serial port in *Canonical Mode* so that each read() call will return util a line comes, and it will return at most one line.

assumes the line separator is \r\n.

Does TCP/IP communication support this feature?

I know that TCP/IP is based on stream and will take 'a','b','c' and '\r','\n' all the same, but I really don't want to parse the message char by char to find '\r','\n' in application.

I hope the TCP can do it for me...

any idea?

Comment: Which amount of data at what data rate do you expect to receive via the serial port? "all you can eat" or just drops of bytes?

Comment: @alk it doesn't matter what the data rate is, now my question is how to do the same thing with TCP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TCP/IP doesn't support "messages"  of any kind.

You need to implement your own kind of protocol.

And if the protocol is that a "messages"'s end is indicated by `\r\n` and you do not know the amount of data up to this EOM indicator in advance you would need to take the burden to inspect the bytes as they flow in.

---

If you however could affort a blocking `fgets()` or similar in case a "message/line" does not fully arrive timely, you could wrap the socket using `fdopen()` and read it via a `FILE*` pointer.

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14686048/694576